# Ocaml Error: Unbound record field label length

Tags: ocaml

This is the error I'm getting and I have no idea why: "Error: Unbound record field label length "
Does anyonw know?

```
let rastavi str =
    let sublist = ref [] in
    let list = ref [] in
    for i = ((str.length str)1) [down]to 0 do
   if str.[i] =' '    then (str.[i] :: !sublist)
  else (list := (!sublist:: !list))   sublist = [] 
  done ;;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using OO notation to get the length of a string.  OCaml uses functional notation.  So it looks like this:

```
String.length str
```

Not like this:

```
str.length (* OO notation, not in OCaml *)
```

**Edit:**

Side comment: this solution is very much an imperative take on the problem.  If you're trying to learn the FP mindset, you should try to think recursively and immutably.  Since this looks like homework, it's very likely a functional solution is what you want.

But here are a few other problems in your original code:

1. You have two expressions next to each other with nothing in between.  If you want to "do" two things, you need to separate them with a semicolon `;` (however, this is imperative style)
2. You're using `=` which compares two values for equality.  If you want to assign a value to a reference you need to use `:=`.  (Imperative style, again.)

Comment: solved that one, thank you, now i have another problem :)
 `let rastavi str =
  let sublist = ref [] in
     let list = ref [] in
     for i = ((String.length str)-1) downto 0 do
     if str.[i] != " "    then (str.[i] :: !sublist)    
     else (list := (sublist:: !list)); sublist := []
  done;;`


This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         char list

Comment: and those errors were there because i've c/p it from terminal and it just erased some signs (beats me why).

Comment: OK.  In the new code look at first `if/then/else`.  The type of the thing after `then` is `char list`, but the type of thing after `else` is `unit`.  This is what the compiler is telling you.  The first expression (after `then`) doesn't "do" anything, it just "is" a list.  You want it to do something.